# How to read a 64-bit two's-complement integer from a binary file using R?

Tags: r, double, bit-manipulation, long-integer

I gather that to represent a 64-bit integer in R I need to use a double. That's fine but I need to read such an integer from a binary file where it is stored as Big Endian 64-bit two's-complement (a java long).

I can of course read the two signed integers in 4 byte chunks like so

```
a = readBin(file, integer(), size=4, endian="big")
b = readBin(file, integer(), size=4, endian="big")
```

But how do I combine them in R to get the double I require?

Comment: Why don't you read it in as a double?

Comment: Because the bit representation of a double is different from the bit representation of a 64-bit integer. To clarify when I say double I mean double precision floating-point as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format. See this for 64-bit integer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29

Comment: I could read it in as a double I suppose but I would have to do some  manipulations to get the desired value from it. Surely this is a problem that has been solved before.

Comment: Oooh, I was thinking you just wanted to get the bit values of the integer into the same bits as a double (even if the number is different). Instead, you want to lose precision when cramming your int64 into a double.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely better to read it in as two integers than as a double. The 2's complement 64 bit representation of small magnitude negative numbers, such as -1, are NaN's in double, and doing arithmetic on them will probably not work out the way you need.

First take the 2's complement issue out. I am going to assume that `a` is the more significant half. If it is negative, note the fact and take the 2's complement of the integer. Flip all the bits, then add one with carry from the `b` add to the `a` add.

Next, convert `a` to double, multiply by 2^32, and add `b`.

If the original value was negative, negate the result.

Note that you may not get the exact answer if the original number was too big.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I could not understand the specifics (what is 'add one with carry from the b add to the a add' for instance) but I realized that as the 64-bit integer being read is actually a unix timestamp in milliseconds and that it will be millions of years into the future till the significant half becomes negative. For this reason I've succeeded with my task by simply calculating a * 2^32 + b and for times about now the number of digits are well within the available precision of double in R. So this has helped me!

Comment: If it is a time stamp, it is more likely to be unsigned than 2's complement, in which case `a*2^32+b` is the correct formula.