# Read a 64bit integer from a binary file in R

Tags: r, long-integer

I am confused, I feel that this question has been [asked](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-April/060566.html) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037725/how-to-read-a-64-bit-twos-complement-integer-from-a-binary-file-using-r) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432916/convert-raw-to-long-in-r) at different points in time, but I am not sure if the answers are correct or still in synch with the current state of R. So here goes:

I have some binary data in a file, and I would like to read a 64-bit integer from the very start of it. Is there currently any sane, non-horrible way of doing this, in R version 3.1.2 (64-bit)?

```
to.read = file("myfile.bin", "rb")
mylong = ???
```

Comment: Use a package that supports 64-bit integers ([bit64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html), [int64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/index.html)).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks for the reply. The `int64` package is defunct, and I don't understand from the `bit64` documentation how to read a 64bit integer from a binary file.

Comment: int64 is not defunct. CRAN archived it because the author/maintainer was unresponsive. That doesn't mean the package doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, but the last update was over 3 years ago, and the documentation doesn't say either how to read a 64bit integer from a binary file.